# How can i create and register a new plugin for CKEDITOR5 in my vue project?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, nuxt.js, ckeditor5

How can i add my custom plugin to CKEDITOR5 in VUE?

I would like to know if there is a way to register a custom plugin with VUE.
The documentation doesn't explain exactly how do it with VUE, the only VUE info are about how init a classic editor.

I would like to add a custom botton in the toolbar, to print my custom HTML e CSS structure.
Thank you!

Comment: can you share your code that you are using? can guide accordingly